# How to mock the test case for Beanutils.setProperty Exception scenario

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I would like to create a test case for this scenario.I tried setting method=null and some other scenario as well. But none of them throwing `InvocationTargetException` or `IllegalAccessException`.

```
doThrow(new IllegalAccessException ).when(BeanUtils).method1()

not working.Any help appreaciated.Thanks

method1{
try
        {
            BeanUtils.setProperty(bean, method,"abc");
        }
        catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException xxxInternalException)
        {
            throw new SOMeException
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mockito.doThrow(new IllegalAccessException()).when(mockObject).method1(Matchers.any()). From your code it doesn't look like complete code. If you still find issue, post complete code.